# Various possibilities about window.location.href.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about:

```
window.location.href.replace
```

Is it possible to apply it to a group of 2 or more words ?

Example:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("-standard", "-standard-upload");
```

I need to replace 2 words with another 2, in the example I change 1 to another 1.

Comment: Do you mean that `"-standard"` appears in the original string more than once, or that you want to also replace a completely different word? Please show an example of the input `href` and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: Example:

www.substellar.it/tiket/stardard/this-is-example

must become

www.substellar.it/upload/stardard/another-words-changed  with window.location.href.replace

Comment: You can chain multiple uses of `.replace()`, like: `x = x.replace("a","b").replace("c","d");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can do this:

```
var a = window.location.href;
a = a.replace("-standard", "-standard-upload");
a = a.replace("old", "new");
window.location.href = a;
```

Comment: Why would the last line need `.replace()`? Just do an assignment `...href = a;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = window.location.href;
str.replace("this", "another").replace("is", "words").replace("example", "changed")
```

As a generic example...

Comment: window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("-standard", "-standard-upload");  but i need to change another 2 words: category in upload

Comment: You are not explaining this properly. Can you please try and explain again so i can help you.

Comment: Example:

www.substellar.it/tiket/stardard/this-is-example

must become

www.substellar.it/upload/stardard/another-words-changed